# rqt_reconfigure doesn't seem to find new nodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Groovy, Ubuntu 12.04.

When I start a new node that uses dynamic_reconfigure, the rqt_reconfigure gui does not see it. The node does appear when the gui is restarted, though. I did not have this issue with the dynamic reconfigure gui on Fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67455/rqt_reconfigure-doesn%27t-seem-to-find-new-nodes/) by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the `$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam list` returns what you want while `rqt_reconfigure` doesn't, then please open a ticket [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues) with sufficient information (incl. how to reproduce, version of ROS, rqt_reconfigure (available by `dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-reconfigure` for example)). If `dynparam list` doesn't return what you want, then there might be something wrong in your nodes.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0